# User login URL for newkly installed Zimbra mail server

Tags: ubuntu, email, email-server, ubuntu-12.04, zimbra

I have managed to install Zimbra 8.0.7 on my Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS server (I had to rebuild my machine and reinstall the OS, so that no other servers other than Zimbra are running - how to reinstall Apache is for another question).

I can access the Zimbra admin page on https://mysite.com:7071

I logged in as admin, and created a user. I am now trying to log in as the user, to see if I can receive an email I sent myself from my hotmail account.

I have tried almost every combination of hostname and domain name I can think of, but I can't get to the page that allows a user to login to check their email in Zimbra.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For clarification, the problem is zimbra login screen doesn't show when you access the http://mysite.com/ ? If yes, what page appears on the screen when you access http://mysite.com/

Comment: @masegaloeh: Thanks for responding. The problem is even more fundamental than that; I don't really know what URL I should use for the user login (I struggled for a whole day to get this far - AFTER I had wiped out my server with a new OS install so Zimbra would be happy). I have tried different URL permutations - but each results with either **Server not found** or **Unable to connect** error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should by default be https://mysite.com or http://mysite.com.

Easy way to findout is search for your user from the admin interface, right click and click view mail.  That will take you to the user interface logged in as that user.

If that still doesn't come up, you have a configuration error somewhere.

Comment: Found this out myself by sheer trial and error (actually, it was https://mail.mysite.com for me), but thanks anyway.